# Using the python shell after running a program in VSCODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Lets say I have a program which just has a class, I want to be able to create instances of the class in the shell and use the methods that the class has without having to write them into the file.

Obviously I can do this in IDLE but how do I do it in VSCODE?

The closest I can get is the start REPL which gives a Python Shell without having the file run as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the class from that file. Let's say your class is named `MyClass` and it is in file `myfile.py`. You can do something like this in your `myscript.py`:

```
# myscript.py
from myfile import MyClass
```

Make sure to create an `__init__.py` file in the root.

Then you can run

```
$python -m myscript
```

Can you share more details?

Answer (score 1):

You can import them.

Let's say you have a file named my_lib.py

my_lib.py

```
class MyClass:
    pass

class MyClass2:
    pass
```

You can open a terminal and change working directory to where `my_lib.py` exists and run python. Then:

```
>>> import my_lib
>>> 
>>> mc = my_lib.MyClass()
>>> mc2 = my_lib.MyClass2()
```

Comment: Would I type the latter into a separate file or into the terminal?

Comment: Both would work. Actually my bad I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Type `python` in integrated Terminal to enter **Interactive mode**, then `import filename` and call function as the following steps:

[image]

Press **Ctrl+Z** to quit interactive mode.